# Angular Material Stepper prevent Step forward if some condition is true

Tags: angular, stepper, mat-stepper

I am wondering how I can skip a step change in Angular Material Stepper.

Every "solution" I see, are not working. I tried also to set the steps regarding on some conditions to editable=false. But this means, that the step cannot edit if it is touched once by a user. Initialized the step with editable=false can be edited :(

I want to skip the step change if the value is equal "stop".

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-stepper-example-yxr3z7)

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild("stepper") stepper;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.navigate(['material']);
  }
  showMaterialPage() {}
}
```

For following use case needed:

User see a custom formular with many input fields, checkboxes and so on. If he made changes but did not submit the changes and he is going to click another dialog, then it should be checked if he has changed values. If it is, a confirm dialog pops up. In this dialog the user will be asked if he will discard the changes or not. If he say not, then the current selected step should not leave. This works for me in my application, but the problem is that the animation is done anyway and so it seams optically that the user is at the next step.

Comment: what if you use *ngIf directive for this step 
  <mat-step label="Second Step" state="number" *ngIf="inputValue !='stop'">
    Second Step
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputValue">
  </mat-step>

Comment: Unfortunalety the user must see the steps.

Comment: <mat-step label="Second Step" state="number" [completed]="inputValue =='stop'"> Second Step <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputValue"> </mat-step>

Comment: Dont work as well. The icons changing to the completed icons as soon the inputValue is "Stop" but I can navigate anyway :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to create css class with name disabled

Write this in your css file **withmaterial.component.css**

```
.disabled{
  pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

And Write this in your **withmaterial.component.html**

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [ngClass]="{'disabled':inputValue =='stop'}" [linear]="false" #stepper (selectionChange)="checkValue($event)" >
```

Comment: Thank you, but this also not the solution for me. The user should be able to click and get a message. I update the use case in my Question, sorry.